# AWS Redshift loading data from S3

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

So I'm trying to load data into my Redshift database from an S3 bucket. I have a table 'Example' which has a field 'timestamp' in the format 'YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'.

Using the [copy query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) to load the data, so I'm able to load for a specific pattern/prefix, but I want to load data after a certain timestamp, say, greater than '2014-07-09 10:00:00'. How do I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. either process the file before you load it to S3 (and upload only the data with timestamp greater than $SOME_TIMESTAMP)
2. use the COPY command to load the file into intermediate table (can be even temp table - as long as you stay within the same session) and then run:

   ```
   insert into YOUR_ORIGINAL_TABLE (select * from YOUR_TEMP_TABLE where timestamp > WHATEVER_YOU_NEED)
   ```